# Change Isotope filter animation effect

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to customize isotope filtering animation. When filtering out the isotope items, all items are hide by fading out plus resizing to an empty item. I want to get rid of the resize effect and just fade out the items. I want also to apply the same effect when displaying previously hidden items - just change opacity from 0.0 to 1.0 and not to show the growing-box effect. I have never worked with jquery animations, so I have no idea if it is possible to make some hack in this direction or something else might help.

Answer (score 2):

In Isotope v2 the animation duration can be changed by changing the transitionDuration option ([see documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html%23transitionduration)).

In v1 the animations were done in CSS. It is mentioned in [the documentation of Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html). You could change the animation effect by altering the CSS.

Comment: This is part of the Isotope v1 documentation. Is there a new way to do this in v2?

Comment: I have the same problem... the link you gave us does not work anymore... The animations are done in which CSS ? (Isotope comes with a script without stylesheet. If you talk about css in the isotope script, i do not want to touch it...)

Comment: The v1 documentation has moved here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to add animation option for Isotop filtering event. just go through
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/  and add include the css3 as you need.